# Restore last windows arrangement in single/multi-monitor setup

Tags: interface, customization

I would like to get the windows that I left open the last time I worked in Blender, either in single or multi-monitor settings.

How can it be done?

Comment: The panel layout saves automatically when you save the file. Do you mean for new files?

Comment: @CharlesL For instance I use the user preferences window for the properties or the outliner too, and both windows are in separate monitors, I woul like to see the same arragment when I open Blender, either in a new file or in a pre-existing one

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure about multiple windows. I know it works on layouts. As for the user preferences, there's an add-on called **QuickPrefs** that allows you to change many options in the properties panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [CharlesL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20/charlesl) pointed out, the UI layout is saved in the .blend file.

- Setup your windows as desired.
- *File > Save Startup File* (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>).

When loading files uncheck the *Load UI* option to prevent the layout changing. This can be made the default by disabling said setting under the *User Preferences > File tab* (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>).

Comment: do you know if this is platform dependent? it kind of works but all the windows open in the main monitor instead of keeping the last arrangement

Comment: I can't currently test this behaviour (single monitor). Sounds like you should [submit a bug report](http://www.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/).

Comment: On linux and windows-xp it restores windows correctly on 2-3 monitor setups, we have a bug in the tracker that reports troubles with windows-7 http://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=34962&group_id=9&atid=498